# Easiest way to know how many views my question got

Tags: support, views

I want to know the easiest way to know how many views my question got?

Comment: Look to the right side.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[image: Below the question title, there is a view counter.]

Comment: +1 for the free hand stuff! :)

Comment: Holy cr.... !!!!!  It is just in front of me!!!

Comment: I know this is a duplicate, but how can I not upvote Freehand Overflow?

Comment: maybe the problem is that the counter is not available in mobile views.